# multiple forms related issue

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private int ValidateData()
{
    int flag = 1;
    if (txtEmpNo.TextLength < 8)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Employee Number must be 8 Digits Long","Message");
        flag = 0;
    }
     return flag;
}
private void btnProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Profile pf = new Profile("");
        if (ValidateData() == 1)
        {
            if (pf!=null)
            {
                pf = new Profile("");
                pf.Focus(); 
            }
            else
            {
               pf = new Profile(txtEmpNo.Text);
               pf.Show();
            }
            Qualification  qa = new Qualification("");
            qa.Close();
            Experience  ex = new Experience("");
            ex.Close();
            History hs = new History("");
            hs.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


        if (ex is IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Employee Not Found");
        }

        else if (ex is OleDbException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Employee Valid No.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

I have created one main form which includes 4 buttons when clicking on these buttons another 4 forms open...i want to implement some functtionality in which if I click on one button it will open respective form and if other forms are open then other forms close automatically...and 2nd thing is if the form already open then not open it up again simply focus it...

I have already done some coding for this but I can not able to get the desire output.

Comment: can u give some suggestion ?? i would really appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to get all the current open  forms from the application. You can access their objects and close them or perform related operations. Like:

```
Form2 frm2 = Application.OpenForms["Form2"] as Form2;
if(frm2 != null)
   frm2.Close();
```

You may also consider few changes to your code, for example your method `ValidateData` could return a `bool` instead of int, and importantly Your catch block should catch the specific exceptions first and then the base `Exception`. Like:

```
try
{
    //your code
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    //handling
}
catch (OleDbException e)
{
    //handling
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    //handling
}
```